# In Windows cmd, how do I run an executable in the current directory (instead of one with the same name in %PATH%) without referring to the full path?

Tags: windows, windows-7, cmd, path-variables

I'm trying to run an executable `foobar` from a directory, but Windows also happens to have an executable (or command) named `foobar`. In UNIX, I'd just write

```
./foobar
```

but Windows cmd doesn't seem to understand that. Given that I don't want to add this directory to my `%PATH%`, is there another way to run the current directory's `foobar` without typing the path explicitly?

Comment: From your comment to paul's answer you should change your question to be "*how do I run an external program that has the same name as an internal command*"

Comment: In Windows, paths have backslashes instead of forward slashes.  So the correct syntax is `.\date` and this will indeed run the executable (if present) and will never run the internal command.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - I can't believe I missed that. I'm just so accustomed to forward-slashes that `.\date` doesn't even look like proper syntax to me. Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Windows always looks in the current directory first before searching the path.
If you are trying to run a command from a program, try "cd"ing to the directory first like so:

```
copy con run_foobar.bat
cd c:\myfoobardirectory
foobar
"<CTRL> + Z"
```

A special case is if you're trying to execute a file that matches the name of an internal command of cmd.exe, such as 'date', in this case, the internal 'date' command will be executed even if you have a local 'date.exe' executable file in the current directory.

You can force the executaion of the local program file by typing the full name 'date.exe' in the current directory, this will override the internal 'date' command.

Notice also that in PowerShell, the behavior is different to Cmd shell, so even if you type in PowerShell in the local directory a command like 'java' or 'java.exe', then the path command will be executed even if there is a local file with the same name. To force the execution of the local file, we would use the linux style './java' or './java.exe'.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I've `cd`ed into `C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin` which contains `date.exe` (a Windows port of UNIX `date`), but issuing `date` or `date.exe` both end up executing Windows' `date`.

Comment: @Andrew and paul, you're both right, you are just talking about two different things. The `date` example that Andrew gives is not an *application*, it's an internal command built in to the Windows command line processor. So yes, it gets executed no matter what. But Windows *does* search the current directory before looking in the rest of the path, so `notepad.exe` will get executed from the current directory if it exists there, rather than the `notepad.exe` bundled with the OS and located in the path.

Comment: @AndrewCheong `date` is a special case because it's also an **internal** command of `cmd.exe` and those indeed overrule files on the disk. The only way you can run the GNU tool is by explicitly using `date.exe` instead of `date`. You should have mentioned that you are trying to run `date` not `foobar` in your question, because that makes a difference

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, that's what I thought, but even when I run `date.exe` (_with_ the `.exe`), the Windows command is run, which is what led me to believe it must be an application...

Comment: @AndrewCheong: when I run `date.exe` while my _current_ directory is the one where `date.exe` is located, then that is used instead of the internal command

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Augh, you're right. I must have accidentally typed `date.exe` from a cmd window that _wasn't_ in that directory at the time (I had a lot of windows open). I agree with you that the question should be renamed in light of the new understanding, but I began with not knowing whether this `foobar` was an application or an internal date, confused by the fact that even `.exe` seemed (by my mistake) to invoke the internal command. So, I think it should remain as is in case anyone else gets confused in the same way. Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: I will accept this answer because as @CodyGray points out, @@paul _is_ correct.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Ah, so I wasn't completely crazy. Typing `date.exe` anywhere else does actually invoke the Windows `date` internal command, even though it's not an `exe`.

Comment: Try temporarily removing date from the PATH variable