# How do I run build files through Strawberry Perl command line?

Tags: windows, perl, windows-10, mingw, strawberry-perl

I am using Strawberry Perl and the command line. I need to know how to install packages like MinGW. I've downloaded MinGW from Github and I need to run the following command-

```
./build --mode=gcc-4.8.1 --arch=x86_64
```

But it doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong? Am I using the wrong command or should I be using something other than the command line?

The error is:

> `'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.`

I'm using Windows 10.

[The code came from here.](https://github.com/StrawberryPerl/mingw-builds)

Comment: What do you mean by "doen't work"?

Comment: `'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: See also [In Windows cmd, how do I run an executable in the current directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23455637/2173773)

Answer (score 2):

The bourne shell command you posted is equivalent to the following Windows command shell commands:

```
"./build" --mode=gcc-4.8.1 --arch=x86_64

.\build --mode=gcc-4.8.1 --arch=x86_64

build --mode=gcc-4.8.1 --arch=x86_64
```

Of course, that assumes `build` refers to a Windows binary or a file otherwise understood by Windows (e.g. a batch file). If not, you have other problems lying ahead.